# how to calculate 256 bit number in numba on a CUDA GPU

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm using python numba and when a number exceed 64 bit it will use cpu instead of gpu so i guess it only support up to 64 bit number. How to calculate 256 bit number in numba(like adding two 256 bit number)?

Comment: Can you call CUDA code from numba? What operations on 256-bit integers do you need beyond addition and multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

> Generally speaking, GPUs are 32-bit machines with 64-bit addressing capability. All 64-bit integer operations are emulated. In the simplest case (logical operations, additions, subtractions) each 64-bit integer operation requires the execution of two 32-bit integer instructions. Very roughly, emulation of 64-bit multiplication requires about twenty 32-bit instructions, 64-bit division requires about eighty 32-bit instructions.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/question-about-64-bit-integer-performance/64147

> GPUs are optimised for doing 3D rendering calculations. Following the history of OpenGL, these are traditionally done using 32-bit floating point numbers arranged as either vectors of four floats or quaternion matrices of 4x4 floats. So that's the capability GPUs are very good at.
>
> **If you want to do floating point with more bits, or 64-bit integerarithmetic, you may find it unsupported or slow.**

https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/121119

Comment: Is it still much faster than CPU?

Comment: Note that the hardware capabilities and instruction set architecture of GPUs tend to fluctuate over time with different GPU architectures. 64-bit integer multiplication seems to map to five instructions on Volta, Turing, Ampere due to some new `IMAD` instructions. 64-bit division still seems to be about 80 instructions, unless it can safely be mapped to a 32-bit division based on the magnitude of the inputs, in which case it requires about 20 instructions.

Comment: @david It depends on the CPU and GPU used. There is typically a factor of 10x in performance between the fastest and slowest GPUs on the market at any given time, and a similar performance span exists for CPUs (e.g. you can get from 4 to 64 cores). The fastest GPUs are typically faster than the fastest CPUs for integer-only work, see examples of cryptocurrency computations and prime number searches, for example.